# Tutorial on Graph Theory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

Can anyone suggest me good online tutorials on Graph Theory ie BFS,DFS and other related Graph algos?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My recommendations:

Introductory - JMT Patrick:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmQR8Xy9DeM

---

Moderately difficult lectures - ADUni and Berkeley:
http://aduni.org/courses/algorithms/index.php?view=cw
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~blum/174notes.html

---

Advanced stuff - MIT:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-315-combinatorial-theory-introduction-to-graph-theory-extremal-and-enumerative-combinatorics-spring-2005/

As a bonus, great presentation from Neo CEO:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UodTzseLh04&feature=related

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Many of these links are very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly recommend to study from topcoder

> http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs1

has both theory and implementation

Answer (score 4):

If you like coding in python, you may check the book:

[Algorithmic Graph Theory](http://code.google.com/p/graphbook/)

The book is GNU-FDL licensed, which means you can read and download all the content for free. And all the source code in the book are provided for Sage. [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is a open source alternative of Matlab. As Sage use python as it's language to write scripts, all source code in Sage are essentially python code with additional modules (from sage).

ps: This Algorithmic Graph Theory is totally a different thing from @Elias's Algorithmic Graph Theory.

Answer (score 2):

Use *[Algorithm Design](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/)* by Tardos and Kleinberg for graph algorithms. 
if you want mathematical graph theory you can read *[Graph Theory](http://diestel-graph-theory.com)* by Rienhard Diestel.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Algorithmic Graph Theory](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/graphTheory.htm)